# Mock function not being called using jest and testing library on react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am using jest and testing library to test a form. But the mock function is not being called. And the last line `expect(mockOnSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();` always fails.

Here's my test code:

`App.test.js`

```js
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

afterEach(cleanup);

test("email and password field are clear for submit", async () => {
  const mockOnSubmit = jest.fn();
  const { getByPlaceholderText, getByText } = render(
    <App onSubmit={mockOnSubmit} />
  );
  const emailNode = getByPlaceholderText(/email/i);
  const passwordNode = getByPlaceholderText(/password/i);

  const testEmail = "test@example.com";
  const testPassword = "123123";

  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.change(emailNode, {
      target: { value: testEmail }
    });
    fireEvent.change(passwordNode, {
      target: { value: testPassword }
    });
  });

  expect(emailNode.value).toBe(testEmail);
  expect(passwordNode.value).toBe(testPassword);

  const submit = getByText(/submit/i);
  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.click(submit);
  });
  expect(mockOnSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

`App.js`

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App({ onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data) }) {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name="email"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        rules={{
          required: `Email is required.`,
          pattern: {
            value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
            message: "Invalid email address"
          }
        }}
        render={({ field }) => {
          return (
            <input
              placeholder="Email"
              type="text"
              key="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
              {...field}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
      <Controller
        name="email"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        rules={{
          required: `Password is required.`
        }}
        render={({ field }) => {
          return (
            <input
              placeholder="Password"
              type="text"
              key="password"
              name="password"
              id="password"
              {...field}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

This minimal implementation is also available at
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-testing-olo4i

Sidenote: This works fine without `react-hook-form` implementation. But as I add handleSubmit from `react-hook-form` it does not work anymore. Here's a [working version](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-testing-forked-vs9ez?file=/src/App.js) by @Florian Motteau where it is working by bypassing `react-hook-form`

Comment: Please put a [mre] _in the question_ - does `App` actually handle the `onSubmit` prop?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is present in the code sandbox link in the end of the question.

Comment: Yes, but that's not _in the question_. Note the guidance in [ask].

Comment: as @jonrsharpe said, please add the related components to the question. But the way, I think the issue is about the Controller, to checking out, change your controlled "Email" and "Password" component with a simple input element and try to pass "register" method from 'react-hook-forms'

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I have added minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

You are checking that the `onSubmit` props has been called, but in your component your are not calling this props when the form is submitted. So the mock you provide in the test will never get called. Besides this, in App.js, the `onSubmit` props is passed an evaluation of `handleSubmit` (`handleSubmit()`), instead you must pass a reference to the handler function (`handleSubmit`, or `() => handleSubmit()`).

Solving these two problems you get :

```js
    // App.js
    export default function App({ onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data) }) {
      const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();
      return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            <EmailField label="Email" name="email" control={control} />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            <PasswordField label="Password" name="password" control={control} />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            <Button name="submit" type="submit" variant="contained">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </form>
      );
    }
```

I also suggets that you use visual text to interact with DOM elements :

```
fireEvent.click(getByText("Submit"));
```

Fixed sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-testing-forked-vs9ez?file=/src/App.js

Finally, you should not have to wrap things in act(), react-testing-library will do this for you, see https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning.

Comment: I am required to add the onSubmit as `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>` this integrates the handleSubmit from react-hook-library. Only then the validation works. Directly applying `onSubmit={onSubmit}` bypasses the `react-hook-form` so that wouldn't work for this case

Comment: I see, but you still need to call a handler passed with a props when the form is submitted without errors. I don't know react-hook-form but somehow you should be able to do that, so your test will pass.

Comment: ya that seems to be the case, I'll try to find something within react-hook-form to solve this